# It is possible to add new signature fields to already signed PDFs?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, acrobat

Let's say we receive a PDF document that is alredy signed.

We'd like to add a new signature field to the document and send it to the person that needs to sign it inside our environment.

We've seen that it's possible with AcrobatPro to directly sign the document, but it's not possible to just add the signature field to the document without signing it. We don't have AcrobatPro licenses for every user on the organization that have to sign external documents, so we're looking for a way to prepare the document for them, so they can sign it just within Acrobat Reader.

We are on a quite big organization (around 3000 ppl) and our ERP already manages everything related to signatures to our own documentation, but we are seeking for a solution to sign external documents that already have been externally signed while our provider evolves a solution inside the ERP.

Comment: It's possible, though depending on how it was last signed, it may be "locked" from further changes/additions, in which case you would be invalidating the original signature. "We don't have AcrobatPro licenses for every user on the organization that have to sign external documents" So you are looking for a free (unpaid) solution? "so we're looking for a way to prepare the document for them" Seems like you are asking for an end user GUI app, but you are asking on a programmers Q&A board. What kind of "solution" are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @Ryan I'd like to know if there is a free solution based on an user app, but, if there only are options based on programing I'd also know it and how/where look for the necessary info to start working on it.

Comment: You are not supposed to ask for recommendations on StackOverflow, especially not for an app. This is the StackExchange you want: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/